# Selecting multiple maximum values? In Sqlite?

Tags: sqlite

Super new to SQLite but I thought it can't hurt to ask.

I have something like the following table (Not allowed to post images yet) pulling data from multiple tables to calculate the TotalScore:

```
Name       TotalScore
Course1       15
Course1       12
Course2        9
Course2       10
```

How the heck do I SELECT only the max value for each course? I've managed use

```
ORDER BY TotalScore LIMIT 2
```

But I may end up with multiple Courses in my final product, so LIMIT 2 etc won't really help me.

Thoughts? Happy to put up the rest of my query if it helps?

Comment: You are not allowed to post images to prevent you from using images [when it is not appropriate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/96125).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can `GROUP` the resultset by `Name` and then use the aggregate function `MAX()`:

```
SELECT Name, max(TotalScore)
FROM my_table
GROUP BY Name
```

You will get one row for each distinct course, with the name in column 1 and the maximum TotalScore for this course in column 2.

**Further hints**

You can only `SELECT` columns that are either grouped by (`Name`) or wrapped in aggregate functions (`max(TotalScore)`). If you need another column (e.g. `Description`) in the resultset, you can group by more than one column:

```
...
GROUP BY Name, Description
```

To filter the resulting rows further, you need to use `HAVING` instead of `WHERE`:

```
SELECT Name, max(TotalScore)
FROM my_table
-- WHERE clause would be here
GROUP BY Name
HAVING max(TotalScore) > 5
```

`WHERE` filters the raw table rows, `HAVING` filters the resulting grouped rows.

Comment: This was exactly what I was after! Worked like a treat - though I do feel like a bit of a goof for not realising it was that simple!

Answer (score 1):

Functions like `max` and `sum` are "aggregate functions" meaning they aggregate multiple rows together. Normally they aggregate them into one value, like `max(totalscore)` but you can aggregate them into multiple values with [`group by`](https://www.w3schools.com/SQL/sql_groupby.asp). `group by` says how to group the rows together into aggregates.

```
select name, max(totalscore)
from scores
group by name;
```

This groups all the columns together with the same name and then does a `max(totalscore)` for each name.

```
sqlite> select name, max(totalscore) from scores group by name;
Course1|15
Course2|12
```